# ElastiCache on aws EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, automation, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have implemented the Elastic Search by installing it into the EC2 as well as consuming the Managed service from aws.
Is there any similar way to install the ElastiCache into the EC2 rather than using managed service from AWS. If there is, how it will be installed in EC2?

Comment: Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) and [Memcached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) both are very popular software for caching the data. You can install these on any platform including the EC2 server. You can follow [memcached installation](https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/install-memcached-on-amazon-linux/) and [Redis installation](https://medium.com/@ss.shawnshi/how-to-install-redis-on-ec2-server-for-fast-in-memory-database-f30c3ef8c35e) to install them on Ubuntu EC2 instance. AWS also offers the managed version of these as ElastiCache, wherein you have to choose which one you want to use ie Redis or Memcached.

As mentioned in the [home page of elastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) :

> Managed, Redis or Memcached-compatible in-memory data store.

Benefits of having a self-managed (wherein you have to install/manage Redis or elasticsearh) is nicly explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/fully-managed-redis/).